# Sampling with replacement events vs. probability of coverage

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a deck of $N$ cards, when $k \leq N$ of the cards bear a mark.  I sample from the deck uniformly and with replacement until I find a marked card.  I then erase the mark, and place the card back in the deck.  The expectation for the number of sampling events necessary to erase all of the marks is not too difficult to derive using the negative binomial distribution, but what is the probability that all $k$ marks are erased as a function of the number of sampling events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're now talking about the situation where
you  take a sample of given size $M$ with replacement, erasing a mark whenever it is found, and you want the probability $P(M)$ that all $k$ originally-marked cards are sampled. The probability that a given set $S$ with $|S|$ members
escapes the sampling is $(N - |S|)/N)^M$.  By inclusion-exclusion the probability
that at least one escapes is
$$ \sum_S (-1)^{|S|-1} \left(\dfrac{N - |S|}{N}\right)^M $$
where the sum is over all nonempty subsets of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$
There are $k \choose s$ such subsets with $|S| = s$, $s = 1 \ldots k$, so
$$P(M) = 1 - \sum_{s=1}^k (-1)^{s-1} {k \choose s} \left(\dfrac{N-s}{N}\right)^M$$

Comment: Thanks for your time here.  To make sure there isn't a mistake with notation, if we have a set of size $n = 100$, some number of marked cards / targets $k = 10$, and $m = 10^3$ sampling events, does $P(M) \approx 0.999568$?

Comment: Yes (where $n = N$ and $m = M$)

Comment: Very good, thanks.