# Sampling with replacement events vs. fraction coverage of a specified set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question is related to a previous one of mine: [Sampling with replacement events vs. probability of coverage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542052/sampling-with-replacement-events-vs-probability-of-coverage)

Here, we are again provided a deck of $N$ cards, when $k \leq N$ of the cards bear a mark.  I sample from the deck uniformly and with replacement until I find a marked card.  I then erase the mark, and place the card back in the deck.

Let $N$ be the size of the deck, let $k$ be the number of marked cards in the deck, and let $m$ be the number of sampling with replacement events.  As a function of $m$, what fraction of the $k$ marks have I erased?

(Secondary question - please feel free to ignore this in an answer!): Returning to my previous question for a moment, is there a way to specify a 1-to-1 mapping between a particular probability of coverage for a set, and an expected fraction coverage of a set?  How can I properly reason about this?

Perhaps to get started, we can write down a simple expression for the fraction of cards we've checked for marks, $P$, as a function of $m$, the number of sampling with replacement events:

$P = (1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^m)$

We can invert this expression to solve for the number of draws $m$ required to achieve some fraction coverage of a random subset of the card deck:

$m = \frac{ln(1-P)}{ln(\frac{N-1}{N})}$

It's not exactly clear to me how to extend this argument to handle the fraction coverage of a specific subset of the card deck (the marked cards).

(10/30/2013): Is the fraction coverage of the specific set just $P$, which, as defined above, is the fraction coverage of the total set of cards?  However, this doesn't seem quite right, since we're dealing with a specific subset of cards.

Comment: "what fraction of the k marks have I erased" Are you thinking of expected values, no?

Comment: " I sample from the deck ... until I find a marked card" Actually, it seems that you sample $m$ times, only that when you find a marked card you unmark it (and return it to the pile?) Is that right?

Comment: @leonbloy Your interpretations are correct on both counts.  I sample $m$ times, and if, during a sampling event, a card is marked, I unmark it.  What is my expected fractional coverage of the set (say, averaged over an arbitrary number of trials where we sample $m$ cards and perform the same procedure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ take the value $1$ if card $i$ has been selected, $0$ otherwise. Then $$E(X_i)=P(X_i=1)=1-\left(1 -\frac{1}{N}\right)^m$$

Assume that the first $k$ cards are marked. Then, the expected number of marked cards that have been selected (and hence unmarked) is

$$E[\sum_{i=1}^k X_i]= k \left(1-\left(1 -\frac{1}{N}\right)^m\right) $$

So, the "expected coverage" $ E[\sum_{i=1}^k X_i]/k$ is the same as for the total number of cards.

Comment: To make sure I understand your final comment, you mean that the expected coverage of a "specific subset" of the cards is equal to the expected coverage of the deck?  In other words, let's assume are cards are unique - the fraction of unique cards I observe after $m$ draws is equal to the fraction of cards in my specific subset with erased marks?

Comment: @user103673 Exactly

Comment: That's a neat result.

Comment: Yes, it's not totally obvious. Remember, however, that we are speaking only of expectations. For example, the probability the subset is fully covered is not equal to the prob the the set is fully covered.

Comment: Do you have any intuition of how to think about how to interpret the expected fraction coverage of my set of marked cards as a probability of coverage for my set of marked cards?  I mean, I can write down a expression for it in light of your answer, but it's a mess.

Comment: No, there is no direct relation between expected coverage and probability of full coverage. You might want to read about the [Coupon collector problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) to get the expected $m$ for full coverage.